# Gravitational waves and Michio Kaku

Tags: cosmology, gravitational-waves, multiverse

I was reading a book from 2005 written by Michio Kaku (Parallel Worlds). In the book it is stated, that if gravitational waves should be detected, then that proves the multiverse theory.

is there any truth behind this statement? Since we detected them 3 times now, I am curious. I am also super new to physics, but extremely interested in it now.

Comment: Just adding some context: It seems like the OP is referring to the existence of  primordial gravotational waves as evidence for inflationary models, which in turn are believed to lead to  a "multiverse" landscape.

Comment: I think that to be a meaningful question, this needs more context, e.g. the passage from the book in which the claim is made. It's certainly false that the discovery of gravitational waves proves anything about the multiverse, but it might be that that isn't really quite what Kaku meant.

Comment: Ya I'm trying to find the actually comment word for word.And i guess i do mean primordial gravitational waves,is there a difference between what we detected and primordial gravitational waves?

Comment: @Freshairfreddy Primordial gravitational waves were created during the big bang: they are everywhere in space, like the cosmic microwave background. These were not yet detected. What we detected are grav. waves created by various collision events long after the big bang. Because the sources are one-off events, these waves are like isolated single "flashes", separated by periods of silence. They are not continuously coming from all directions like the primordial waves.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure gravitational waves don't prove any "multiverse" theory. At most they "prove" general relativity and are consistent with any theory that is consistent with general relativity.

Comment: Agree. The big thing about this experiment is, that it is the first direct experimental confirmation that gravity is mediated by a field (that the field has its own degrees of freedom).